Movie where a demon jumps from person to person through their eyes
I have been searching for this movie from maybe the late 90's or early 00's stages.
Things that I know about the movie:

In the start there is a key found in a necklace around a skeleton of a templar knight 
This key unlocks the devil which lies hidden behind the door in a church protected by an army of templar
There is a templar knight that is sent to retrieve this key; however, he is faced with a task to fight a demon that also wants the key to unlock the devil
This demon jumps from host to host by looking into their eyes 

It was an English movie. I must have seen it like about 10 years ago.

Sounds like The Minion from 1998 with Dolph Lundgren.

New York, Christmas Eve, 1999 - at the dawn of the new millennium - a subway construction crew unearths an eight hundred year old Celtic skeleton and a mysterious key. Archeologist Karen Goodleaf is called in to determine the meaning of the discovery. News of the discovery reaches a Middle East monastery where the warrior monks known as the Knights Templer - an ancient sect entrusted with protecting holy relics - choose their best pupil, Lukas (Dolph Lundgren) to face the diabolical threat. As Lukas races to New York, an evil Minion seizes Karen and uses its body like a parasite and host. Lukas arrives just in time to rescue Karen and despatch the Minion. The Minion takes hold of another host - revealing that it is immortal. As it cuts a path of destruction through the city, decimating a parking garage and leaving a trail of death, Karen realizes that the Minion can't be killed - but only delayed from finding a new host. 

The Minion moves from body to body through the eyes, which glow red. Here's the trailer:



